# HubSpot meetings embed code (iFrame container) not working on Angular 14

Tags: angular, hubspot

We have an Angular 14 website and I'm trying to implement the Meetings iFrame container. However it's not showing up.

I added the js file to index.html:

```html
  <!-- Start of Meetings Embed Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.hsappstatic.net/MeetingsEmbed/ex/MeetingsEmbedCode.js"></script>
    <!-- End of Meetings Embed Script -->
```

And I have the following in our .component.html file:

```html
<!-- Start of Meetings Embed Script -->
            <div class="meetings-iframe-container" data-src="https://meetings.hubspot.com/erwin-de-moel?embed=true">
            </div>
<!-- End of Meetings Embed Script -->
```

Nothing happens and no console errors.
How do I get this working on our Angular 14 site?

Answer (score 0):

You can try injecting the JS from the Angular component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  const myScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  myScriptElement.src =
  'https://static.hsappstatic.net/MeetingsEmbed/ex/MeetingsEmbedCode.js';
  document.body.appendChild(myScriptElement);
}
```